# How to display a CSV on an HTML page using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, csv, onedrive

I am currently attempting to display a csv files contents on an HTML page. The scope of my project is live update a webpage based on the changes made to an excel file on Onedrive. Thus far I have set up a Power Automate flow that takes the Excel Onedrive file and stores it as a CSV in the same folder on the OneDrive every 2 minutes. My first and slightly unrelated issue here is:

1. I am unable to reference the CSV file on my OneDrive desktop from my App.js code because it is outside of the src folder. However, I am unable to user the Power Automate flow to store the CSV file locally on my desktop (in the src folder).

Regardless, to by-pass that issues I currently just copying and pasting the CSV file into my src folder for testing purposes. However, I cannot get my CSV to display on the webpage. My App.js code can be seen below.

```
import React from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
import "C:/Users/isaacl5/ReactProjects/my-app/src/App.css";
import "C:/Users/isaacl5/ReactProjects/my-app/src/Excel/output.csv"

export default function App() {
 const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   async function getData() {
     const response = await fetch("/output.csv");
     const reader = response.body.getReader();
     const result = await reader.read(); // raw array
     const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
     const csv = decoder.decode(result.value); // the csv text
     const results = Papa.parse(csv, { header: true }); // object with { data, errors, meta }
     const rows = results.data; // array of objects
     setRows(rows);
     console.log(rows);
   }
   getData();
 }, []); // [] means just do this once, after initial render
 return (
   <div>
     {rows.map((row) => {
       return (
         <div key={row.id} class={row.location}>
           <h2>{row.location}</h2>
         </div>
       );
     })}
   </div>
 );
}
```

And here is the contents of my CSV file:

```
Project,Location,StartDayandHour,EndDayandHour,UtilityA,UtilityB,UtilityC
Air Compressor,Compressor room 2,45140,45140.3333333333,Y,N,N
LGV Aisle,LGV lane,45140.25,45143.7083333333,N,Y,N
```

It is followed by a lot of commas, that represent empty cells, I removed those for spatial reasons on this post.

When I run my code, it does not display the location on my webpage, however when the code runs

```
console.log(rows);
```

It displays the following:

[image: Console log display]

Which is the default index file that loads when you create a react project. I just cannot understand how this is stores in the rows variable, when I specifically tell the function to fetch "/output.csv".

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

From my understanding of the code I fetch my CSV file, store it as an array of objects, and then return a list of locations (compressor room 2, LGV Lane) to printed on the webpage.

Furthermore, if anyone has a better path I can take as far as this process please let me know. The easiest way in my mind would be to read the data directly from the onedrive excel file, I was unable to do that. Regardless I am up for suggestions.

Thank you all! Let me know if you have any questions.